# Strange output when building Tailwind through PostCSS (Laravel Mix)

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm using Laravel Mix and PostCSS to build Tailwind.

Everything works, I can even Purge unused styles.

I have strange outputs when I build (a LOT of these) :

```
--tw-space-y-reverse [
   {
     index: 40,
     token: '-',
     type: 9,
     eval: [Function: sub],
     precedence: 1,
     show: '-'
   },
   {
     index: 40,
     token: '-',
     type: 9,
     eval: [Function: sub],
     precedence: 1,
     show: '-'
   }
]
```

I'm using the latest TailwindCSS version.
Here is the relevant part of my webpack.mix.js :

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
require('laravel-mix-purgecss');

let tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
mix.postCss('resources/css/tailwind.css', 'public/css/soumettre202101.css', [
  tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
]);
```

I don't even know where to start. I don't know what's causing this.

Any lead will be appreciated!

I can remove the output by disabling this core plugins (in my tailwind.config.js) :

```
module.exports = {
  corePlugins: {
    space: false,
    ringWidth: false,
    ringColor: false,
    ringOffsetWidth: false,
    ringOffsetColor: false,
    ringOpacity: false,
    divideOpacity: false,
    divideColor: false,
    divideWidth: false,
  }
}
```

Even more strange : if I only disable "space", the output changes from the one above to the same thing but with --tw-ring-width-reverse, as if the last plugin used produces the output...

Comment: Does this https://github.com/spatie/laravel-mix-purgecss#important-notice-for-mixpostcss-or-postcssconfigjs-users help?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, we are already using it.

Comment: No, I mean, this specific configuration for plugin to use with PostCSS. I'm using Laravel+Tailwind with postcss, but never had such a problem. The only difference I see - I'm not using laravel-mix-purgecss for purging, so my guess was something wrong with its configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by ugrapding Laravel Mix to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that helps, but I will show you my config that seems to be working fine (using Sass), I removed some irrelevant parts.

**webpack.mix.js**

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix.sass('resources/sass/tailwind.scss', 'public/css')
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [ tailwindcss('./resources/tailwind.config.js') ],
    })
    .version();
```

**tailwind.scss**

```
@import "~tailwindcss/base";

@import "~tailwindcss/components";

@import "~tailwindcss/utilities";
```

and finally **tailwind.config.js**

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  purge: {
      content: [
          './resources/views/**/*.blade.php',
          './resources/js/**/*.js',
      ],
      defaultExtractor: content => content.match(/[\w-/.:]+(?<!:)/g) || []
  },
  theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
        },
        colors: {
            // some custom colors
            gray: colors.trueGray,
            indigo: colors.indigo,
            red: colors.rose,
            yellow: colors.amber,
            bluegray: colors.blueGray,
            orange: colors.amber,
            teal: colors.teal,
            pink: colors.pink,
            green: colors.green,
        },
    },
  },
  variants: {
     gridColumn: ['responsive', 'hover'],
     gridColumnStart: ['responsive', 'hover'],
     gridColumnEnd: ['responsive', 'hover'],
  },
  plugins: [
      require('tailwindcss'),
      require('autoprefixer'),
      require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
      require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
      require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
  ],
};
```

When I run `nom run dev` everything seems to be fine, there is no output like you showed but I have things like this:

```
.space-y-11 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]){
  --tw-space-y-reverse: 0;
  margin-top: calc(2.75rem * calc(1 - var(--tw-space-y-reverse)));
  margin-bottom: calc(2.75rem * var(--tw-space-y-reverse));
}
```

Obviously later only those that are really used in blade/js files are in final file when I run `npm run prod`